# Maxima: creating a function that acts on parts of a string

Tags: regex, function, maxima

**Context:** I'm using Maxima on a platform that also uses KaTeX. For various reasons related to content management, this means that we are regularly using Maxima functions to generate the necessary KaTeX commands.

I'm currently trying to develop a group of functions that will facilitate generating different sets of strings corresponding to KaTeX commands for various symbols related to vectors.

---

**Problem**

I have written the following function `makeKatexVector(x)`, which takes a string, list or list-of-lists and returns the same type of object, with each string wrapped in `\vec{}` (i.e. `makeKatexVector(`string`)` returns `\vec{`string`}` and `makeKatexVector(["`a`","`b`"])` returns `["\vec{`a`}", "\vec{`b`}"]` *etc*).

```
/* Flexible Make KaTeX Vector Version of List Items */
makeKatexVector(x):= block([ placeHolderList : x ],
            if stringp(x)   /* Special Handling if x is Just a String */
            then placeHolderList : concat("\vec{", x, "}")
            else        if listp(x[1])   /* check to see if it is a list of lists */
                    then        for j:1 thru length(x) 
                            do placeHolderList[j] : makelist(concat("\vec{", k ,"}"), k, x[j] ) 
                        else        if  listp(x)   /* check to see if it is just a list */
                            then  placeHolderList    : makelist(concat("\vec{", k, "}"), k, x) 
                            else    placeHolderList : "makeKatexVector error: not a list-of-lists, a list or a string", 
        return(placeHolderList));
```

Although I have my doubts about the efficiency or elegance of the above code, it seems to return the desired expressions; however, I would like to modify this function so that it can distinguish between single- and multi-character strings.

In particular, I'd like multi-character strings like `x_1` to be returned as `\vec{x}_1` and **not** `\vec{x_1}`.

In fact, **I'd simply like to modify the above code so that `\vec{}` is wrapped around the first character of the string, regardless of how many characters there may be.**

---

**My Attempt**

I was ready to tackle this with brute force (*e.g.* transcribing each character of a string into a list and then reassembling); however, the *real* programmer on the project suggested I look into "Regular Expressions". After exploring that endless rabbit hole, I found the command `regex_subst`; however, I can't find any Maxima documentation for it, and am struggling to reproduce the examples in the related documentation [here](http://ds26gte.github.io/pregexp/index-Z-H-3.html).

Once I can work out the appropriate regex to use, I intend to implement this in the above code using an `if` statement, such as:

```
if slength(x) >1 
then {regex command}
else {regular treatment}
```

**If anyone knows of helpful resources on any of these fronts, I'd greatly appreciate any pointers at all.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you got the regex approach working, that's great. My advice about handling subscripted expressions in TeX, however, is to avoid working with names which contain underscores in Maxima, and instead work with Maxima expressions with indices, e.g. `foo[k]` instead of `foo_k`. While writing `foo_k` is a minor convenience in Maxima, you'll run into problems pretty quickly, and in order to straighten it out you might end up piling one complication on another.

E.g. Maxima doesn't know there's any relation between `foo`, `foo_1`, and `foo_k` -- those have no more in common than `foo`, `abc`, and `xyz`. What if there are 2 indices? `foo_j_k` will become something like `foo_{j_k}` by the preceding approach -- what if you want `foo_{j, k}` instead? (Incidentally the two are `foo[j[k]]` and `foo[j, k]` when represented by subscripts.) Another problematic expression is something like `foo_bar_baz`. Does that mean `foo_bar[baz]`, `foo[bar_baz]` or `foo_bar_baz`?

The code for `tex(x_y)` yielding `x_y` in TeX is pretty old, so it's unlikely to go away, but over the years I've come to increasing feel like it should be avoided. However, the last time it came up and I proposed disabling that, there were enough people who supported it that we ended up keeping it.

Something that might be helpful, there is a function `texput` which allows you to specify how a symbol should appear in TeX output. For example:

```
(%i1) texput (v, "\\vec{v}");
(%o1)                       "\vec{v}"
(%i2) tex ([v, v[1], v[k], v[j[k]], v[j, k]]);
$$\left[ \vec{v} , \vec{v}_{1} , \vec{v}_{k} , \vec{v}_{j_{k}} , 
 \vec{v}_{j,k} \right] $$
(%o2)                         false
```

`texput` can modify various aspects of TeX output; you can take a look at the documentation (see `? texput`).

Comment: So much useful information here, can't thank you enough! FWIW up until now I haven't fed Maxima anything from (Ka)TeX, I'm actually just using it to generate KaTeX commands (which sounds like a weird thing to do, out of context, I realize), but this will be very helpful when I inevitably get to this side of the fence. Greatly appreciate your time & advice!

Answer (score 1):

While I didn't expect that I'd work this out on my own, after several hours, I made some progress, so figured I'd share here, in case anyone else may benefit from the time I put in.

1. to load the regex in wxMaxima, at least on the MacOS version, simply type `load("sregex");`. I didn't have this loaded, and was trying to work through our custom platform, which cost me several hours.
2. take note that many of the arguments in the [linked documentation](http://ds26gte.github.io/pregexp/index.html) by Dorai Sitaram occur in the reverse, or a different order than they do in their corresponding Maxima versions.
3. not all the "pregexp" functions exist in Maxima;

In addition to this, escaping special characters varied in important ways between wxMaxima, the inline Maxima compiler (running within Ace editor) and the actual rendered version on our platform; in particular, the inline compiler  often returned `false` for expressions that compiled properly in wxMaxima and on the platform. Because I didn't have `sregex` loaded on wxMaxima from the beginning, I lost a lot of time to this.

Finally, the regex expression that achieved the desired substitution, in my case, was:

```
regex_subst("\vec{\\1}", "([[:alpha:]])", "v_1");
```

which returns `vec{v}_1` in wxMaxima (**N.B.** none of my attempts to get wxMaxima to return `\vec{v}_1` were successful; escaping the backslash just does not seem to work; fortunately, the usual escaped version `\\vec{\\1}` does return the desired form).

I have yet to adjust the code for the rest of the function, but I doubt that will be of use to anyone else, and wanted to be sure to post an update here, before anyone else took time to assist me.

**Always interested in better methods / practices or any other pointers / feedback.**